# VPS problems... I think?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, vps

I am very new to linux so please forgive any ignorance. I setup a VPS using Ubuntu 10.04, apache2, mySQL, and PHP.

Everything has worked perfectly except for two things:

1: my IP address is assigned to Germany (we are in the US)
2: my Google Chrome Sniffer (it places an icon in the address bar with helpful hints as to what programs the websites uses: analytics, wordpress, etc...) is no longer working on my site.

Are these two 'problems' even problems? If so, I would love your input!

My Chrome Sniffer 'problem' is not really a problem for me at all, I just wonder if it is a **sign** of a problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There may be SEO implications for a US site with a German IP address - i.e. when trying to return "local" search results it may not include your website because it thinks it's in Germany. I think you can use Google Webmaster Tools though to implicitly set your country to US.
2. Sorry, can't really help here. If you do use google analytics for example and this addon is not showing it anymore, check in the page source if google analytics is in fact loading. If it is, then its probably just some problem with your addon (which I'm not familiar with).